# Converting UNIX time to Date in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

As title, is it possible in Google Data Studio to Convert Unix Timestamp to a human-readable date?
For example, to convert '1618087345 to a date format consisting of year month day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, to treat a field with an Unix timestamp as a date, you don't need to do anything.  Just mark the field as "Date & Time" type and you're done.

Check this Data Source and Dashboard as an example:

- [Data Source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uZ6CDz80F4F4403SJsm6SkfeNqmq9FHXWg7n_nPL1MI/edit?usp=sharing)
- [Dashboard](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c9b1054f-ec24-416f-8a7b-0884024df3b1)

If you really need to convert manually for whataver reason, you may want to have a look into [`DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE` function](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9735234).

Comment: Except that DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE expects an INTEGER type, and not a NUMBER type, which so annoying and mismatches on the type when the argument comes from a BigQuery or Google Sheet field. I was unable to CAST NUMBER to INTEGER.

Comment: when trying this solution I get this message: Can't convert to date
Looker Studio can't convert created (Number) to a Date or Date & Time because it doesn't recognize the date format.